# How to add the elements of a list in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a list as belows:

```
test = {a[2] r[5] f[6] t[8]} {d[32] g[66] k[88]} {w[2] e[33]}
```

The size of the test list is variable and can have any number of elements.

I want the total to be calculated as:

total = 4 + 3 + 2 = 9

I am trying something like this but it gives an error.

```
set result ""
set index1 ""  
foreach index1 [llength $test] {
        set value [llength [lindex $test $index1]]
        result1 = expr [$value + $result1]
        puts $result1
}
```

It gives the error below:

```
invalid command name "0"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do something for every member of a list, always use `foreach`, and `incr` is great for various sorts of counting things. In this case:

```
set total 0;  # In case the input list is empty
foreach sublist $test {
    incr total [llength $sublist]
}
# The value you are looking for is in the “total” variable
```